Javascript server html not loading js client script (socket.io express html
The basic issue is that when I try to remove the js code from being directly in the html file (everything works 100% perfectly with js directly in html, but as I try to add components and things become more complex, I want to have multiple html and js files for the front end) to a separate js file, and I load the server localhost page, it cannot find the js file. I understand that I have:

maindir/

client/

index.html
client.js


server.js
{other files that server.js uses for backend stuff}



And that when I start a server and navigate to localhost:3000, the app.get -> res.sendfile passes the html file to the user on the webpage and that the js file cannot be found, given that the cwd of the webpage is not the maindir/client/ dir, but I can't figure out how to get the js file to the client through the server without directly including the code in the html file. Screenshots below:
server.js code of interest:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);


const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);
// const io = require("socket.io")(3000, {
//    cors: {
//       origin: ['http://localhost:3000']
//    }
// })

const lib = require('./library');
const dr = require('./Driver');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/index.html');
//   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/client.js');
//   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/photo_server.jpg');
});

var users = [];
var n = 0;
var data;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

client.js code of interest:
// let msg = "pre anything";
// var item = document.createElement('li');
// item.textContent = msg;
// messages.appendChild(item);
// window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);

// ES6 import or TypeScript
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
// CommonJS
// const io = require("socket.io-client");
 // start javascript section
// var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/');
var socket = io();
// const socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3001");

// msg = "post socket";
// var item = document.createElement('li');
// item.textContent = msg;
// messages.appendChild(item);
// window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
   
 // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 // START input
 // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

 // this will submit the chat via emit to server (from 1 user)
 var form = document.getElementById('form');
 var input = document.getElementById('input');

 form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

html file
browser error when running server with code in separate file
I tried what was mentioned above
